# No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I installed `cryptography` using the `pip install cryptography -t .` in my windows command prompt then I zipped it and uploaded in AWS Lambda, but whenever I run the code in AWS lambda I get the below error

```
No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding
```

Please anyone help me to get rid of this error.

I am using python 3.6 in my windows system

Comment: Are you installing it with the SAME python version as you're using in AWS?

Comment: Yes I am using 3.6 in both local and AWS Lambda

Comment: Have you seen this look at the section WITH dependencies? I don't know much about python so just spitballing here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: is your main code locates with cryptography folder at the same depth? For example, /path/to/main.py is same as /path/to/cryptography

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the cryptography package worked for me

```
pip3 install --upgrade cryptography
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of

`python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`

`python -m pip install –-upgrade pip`

`python -m pip install –-upgrade cryptography`

`python -m pip install --upgrade cffi`

Verify the deployment procedure and make necessary updates to required packages

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for a while, and I found that it had to do with how I was creating layers for the lambda function.

The path of the libraries that you are uploading should be [root]/python/lib/python[version].[minor version]/site-packages

Whenever I uploaded it in any other way, Lambda did not recognize the dependencies.

This worked for Python3.9, so in the case of the cryptography library, the zip that I uploaded for my lambda layer was in the structure of /python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/[cryptography dump].

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem and Available solutions:

***TLDR:** you should always properly install `cryptography` directly on runtime, if possible, instead of packaging and shipping; otherwise  manually build it for the target runtime (with all system external dependencies links referenced). Installing with `pip install cryptography -t` on local system and then packaging for target system can cause dependencies issues.*

Cryptography depends on many non-python, external modules and system dependencies, tools and binaries, to be installed, compatible and available to the Runtime on execution (Lambda runtime) to work.

When the module is installed locally and then packaged, and shipped to another runtime, usually this does not have these dependencies, or has incompatible ones; this may lead to issues. The best way to fixing this is by directly installing `cryptography` on the target system, only through `pip install` (upgrading pip first) (without shipping with .zip ). The `pip install` will properly install all compatible dependencies.

In the AWS Lambda case, if you do not have access to `pip install` directly on the runtime you should try to build the .zip package  using same system versions, and same python version (maybe use a EC2 virtual machine) so that the final exported bundle is compatible with target system tools and dependencies.

Last resort, you will need to follow instructions to build your own custom installation from source and properly install and link those external dependencies used by your runtime. Follow `cryptography` installation documentation instructions [Link to cryptography Documentation Build instructions](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/)